# How to handle DataContext that binds to Generic ViewModel, and access the Generic ViewModel in CodeBehind properly in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

I have a generic ViewModel:

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class GenericViewModel<T>
{
    public IList<T> SomeList {get; set;}
}
```

I have to bind the MainWindow's DataContext to this `GenericViewModel`. However, I do not know how I should put the thing for `<T>`:

**MainWindow's Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new GenericViewModel<????>(); // What should I put
    }
}
```

The reason I would like to make the ViewModel generic is, I want the List inside it to accept any class's object passed to it, and I have made several dummy class to test it:

**DummyModel1**

```
public class DummyModel1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

**DummyModel2**

```
public class DummyModel2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So, how should I do?

In addition, is there any way to make the application know what the object class passed in before initialize the application?

Comment: You can use `this.DataContext = new GenericViewModel<object>();`

Comment: @Aakanksha then if I do so, how to I pass a DummyObject into it?

Comment: Just add it to the list. If you want to have objects of different types in a single list, it doesn't need to be generic at all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have instances of multiple types in a single list, you don't need a generic view model. All you need is this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> SomeList { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<object>();
}
```

Assign it to the MainWindow's DataContext and add any type of object:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.SomeList.Add(new DummyModel1 { Name = "?", ID = 1 });
    vm.SomeList.Add(new DummyModel2 { Name = "?", ID = 2, ... });
}
```

In XAML make sure you have different DataTemplate for the different types like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DummyModel1}">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DummyModel2}">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then an ItemsControl (or a derived element like a ListBox) would automatically use the appropriate DataTemplate for the elements in its ItemsSource collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}"/>
```

Comment: If I don't use Generic and use object instead of T, it states that "Cannot convert from DummyModel to object.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `DummyModel` base class that `DummyModel2` and any other specialized class inherits from:

```
public class DummyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class DummyModel2 : DummyModel
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

...and use an `IList<DummyModel>` property to which you can add any type of `DummyModel`:

```
public class GenericViewModel
{
    public IList<DummyModel> SomeList {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to be able to objects of *any* type to the collection, it makes no sense to use either generics or a strongly-typed `IList`.

Comment: @TomFong: Did you try this or what happened?